# Error "Missing number, treated as zero" - first compilation worked, second created the error

Tags: errors, compiling, texmaker

I hope some of you can help me with that problem. It is however difficult to give a minimal example. Here is the Problem:

I'm writing my master's thesis with TEXmaker and have splitted my document by using the `\input` command. The compilation always worked fine. But suddenly there is the error message

> ! Missing number, treated as zero.  \advance 
>   l.15 ...egion (MP).\relax }}{29}{table.caption.28}
>   A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.

appears. The text location given in the message hasn't been changed and worked before. And the strange thing is, when I masked all inputs with `%` the compilation worked fine, I removeed the `%`again, the compilation still worked fine. I ran BIBTEX and PDFLATEX and it worked fine. I ran PDFLATEX for the last time (as it is recommended to get all refences right) the error appeared again with the identical message.

I again masked all inputs and ran PDFLATEX, the error remained. I repeated PDFLATEX, now it worked again though I haven't changed the code.

Please, does anyone know this weird error? It started when I used the "Fast Translate" (PDFLATEX + BIB(LA)TEX + 2x PDFLATEX + View PDF) in TEXmaker

Comment: Sorry, but without a minimal working example, this is impossible to answer. Take a close look at your table captions and delete the aux-files between checking.

Comment: The thing is, when I remove the part given in the error message and compile, the same message comes. When I compile again then the error message shows me another part of the code. And the line number given by the message is different from the line in which the code fragment is :-(

Comment: There is an error in the code, and we don't know your code. A [simple algorithm to find the cause](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) (<- Link) is availabe to help you.

Answer (score 1):

(this was intended as a comment, but it's too long.)

the problem appeared with the *fourth* run.  that means it happened
because of some change that was made with the *third* run.

so what happened in the third run?

pdflatex was run after biblatex, and that made the information
on the `\cite`s available in the `.aux` file.  so the problem is
almost certainly associated with one of the `\cite`s,
but surely by something in the `.aux` file.

look in the line where the problem is reported and see if there's
some sort of cross reference.
is it in a "moving argument" like a section heading or a caption?
if so, there are other questions here dealing with that.

the solution in such a case is usually to add `\protect` before the
`\cite` or `\ref` in the argument.  but we can't be specific without
an example to experiment with.

Answer (score 0):

To speed up my compilation I exclueded parts with `%`, for example the titlepage added with

```
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{-1}
\begin{titlepage}
\input{../Titlepage/Titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\end{titlepage}
```

However I only masked the the entrys from begin to end titlepage. 
When I also mask the setcounter to `%\setcounter{page´}{-1}`the code finally worked again.

I really don't know why the error sometimes appeared not before the fourth compilation run.

Thanks for you motivation, Johannes_B

Comment: this isn't an answer; it should be incorporated in the question.

Comment: Well but it solved my problem. So isn't this the solution?